# Hit the action from xslt in anchor tag

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, xslt

I have a anchor tag in xslt.

I want to create a view page with respect to
 `<a href="{@Name}/{current()/@ID}">`

My url is just like:

```
http://localhost:1882/blog/Yoga/19
```

Here blog is my controller..
i want to make a view page where All the details(ID=19) will bind in xslt
How to call the controller and how to make view page???

This is my .xslt page:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Parent">
               <div class="grid-col-3">
                 <ul>
                   <h4><a href="{@ParentName}/{current()/@Id}">
                   <xsl:value-of select="@ParentName"></xsl:value-of>
                   </a></h4>
                   <xsl:for-each select="/BlogCategories/BlogCategory[@ParentID = current()/@Id]">
                     <!--<xsl:if test="@ParentID=$Id">-->
                     <li class="lis">
                       <a href="{@Name}/{current()/@ID}">
                         <xsl:value-of select="@Name"></xsl:value-of>
                       </a>
                     </li>
                     <!--</xsl:if>-->
                   </xsl:for-each>
                 </ul>
               </div>
             </xsl:for-each>
```

Here is my blog controller:

```
public ActionResult addblogxml(string actiontype)
        {
            if(actiontype== "Submit")
            {
                var blog = _api.GetAllBlogCategory().ToList();
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/XmlFiles/BlogCategory.xml"));
                writer.WriteLine(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>");   
                writer.WriteLine(blog[0]);
                writer.Close();
                var xDocument = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XmlFiles/BlogCategory.xml"));
                string xml = xDocument.ToString();
                ViewBag.BlogCategoryXML = xml;
            }
            return View("~/Areas/BMS/Views/CategoryBlog/addblogxml.cshtml");
        }
```

what i need to do??
Is there any thing justlike id and name is required??

How to hit the action with `<a href="{@Name}/{current()/@ID}">`??

Comment: What do you mean by "hit"?

Comment: How to call the action with <a href="{@Name}/{current()/@ID}">